# Rails 3.1 Ajax forms don't show validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using updated pre Ruby on Rails on Ruby 1.9.2 (with rvm), and made a new test application with

```
$ rails generate scaffold Project name:string
```

and

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

I change

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for @project, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

I can now still (without any changes in the controller) add new items to the project. If I try to add with empty in the name field, it will not add anything (validates_presence_of :name stops this), but I don't get any validation error messages. I have tried the same on an application converted from 3.0 I'm working on with same results. Here I had:

```
class KursController < ApplicationController
  # GET /kurs
  # GET /kurs.xml
  respond_to :js, :html
```

and:

```
def update
  @kur = Kur.find(params[:id])
  @kur.update_attributes(params[:kur])
  flash[:notice] = "Lagret" if @kur.save
  respond_with( @kur, :layout => !request.xhr? )
end
```

In 3.1 I get no validation error messages. Is this because of a bug in Ruby on Rails 3.1 or something I should do different?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to call these errors. Do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
<%= render :partial => 'my_error_messages_for', :locals => {:collection => @project} %>
```

In "_my_error_messages_for.html.erb":

```
<% if collection.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% collection.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

You can create a helper for this work.

Comment: This dosn't fix it. I get error messages with normal forms. It's Ajax forms (":remote => true") who don't show errors. Maybe I have to catch the error messages in a js.erb file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Ruby on Rails will automatically include the partial that you've requested. You'll need to add some JavaScript  code to get it to work correctly. Something like this I imagine:

```
// Application.js
$("form").bind("ajax:success", function (event, data, status, xhr) {
    $(event.target).replaceWith(data);
});
```